# Consulta sql desde vb6 a oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, vb6

necesito hacer un insert into desde VB6 a una base de Oracle, cambié el procedimiento , de acuerdo a la ayuda que ya me dieron, respetando la sintaxis de Oracle.  pero ahora obtengoi
Ahora obtengo el error "invalid column name" , podrían ayudarme con alguna idea de como resolver ?

Gracias ! Copio el código :

```html
Private Sub inserta_registro()
Dim cad As String
Dim a1 As String * 1
Dim b1 As String * 1

    var_cod_val = CLng(txtCodVal)
    var_monto = CLng(txtMonto)
    var_cod_verif = CLng(txtCodVer)
    var_ref_form = CLng(txtRef)
    a1 = "S"
    b1 = "N"
    
    cad = "INSERT INTO CDJ.CDJ_CONSULTAS_PFS " & _
    "(ID_CONSULTA_PFS,FC_CONSULTA_PFS,ID_VLT," & _
    " HS_CONSULTA,MIN_CONSULTA,HS_RTA,MIN_RTA,HS_PAGO,MIN_PAGO," & _
    " TIPO,FL_TICKET,FL_RTA_CDJ,TIPO_DE_FALLA, COD_VALIDACION, MONTO," & _
    " COD_VERIFICADOR,REF_FORMULARIO,ID_MOTIVO_TICKET,ID_ASISTENTE_SIC," & _
    " ID_SUPERVISOR_SIC,ID_MOTIVO_CONSULTA_PFS,US_CREACION,TS_CREACION," & _
    " US_ULT_MODIF,TS_ULT_MODIF,COD_TIPO_VALIDACION)" & _
    " VALUES(:ID_CONSULTA_PFS,:FC_CONSULTA_PFS,:ID_VLT," & _
    "  :HS_CONSULTA,:MIN_CONSULTA,:HS_RTA,:MIN_RTA,:HS_PAGO,:MIN_PAGO," & _
    "  :TIPO,:FL_TICKET,:FL_RTA_CDJ,:TIPO_DE_FALLA,:COD_VALIDACION,:MONTO," & _
    "  :COD_VERIFICADOR,:REF_FORMULARIO,:ID_MOTIVO_TICKET,:ID_ASISTENTE_SIC,:ID_SUPERVISOR_SIC," & _
    "  :ID_MOTIVO_CONSULTA_PFS,:US_CREACION,:TS_CREACION," & _
    "  :US_ULT_MODIF,:TS_ULT_MODIF,:COD_TIPO_VALIDACION)"
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_CONSULTA_PFS", reg_actual, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "FC_CONSULTA_PFS", Date, 1, 12
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_VLT", var_slot, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "HS_CONSULTA", val(txthora(0).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "MIN_CONSULTA", val(txtmin(0).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "HS_RTA", val(txthora(1).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "MIN_RTA", val(txtmin(1).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "HS_PAGO", val(txthora(2).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "MIN_PAGO", val(txtmin(2).text), 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "TIPO", var_tipo, 1, 96
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "FL_TICKET", var_ticket, 1, 96
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "FL_RTA_CDJ", a1, 1, 96
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "TIPO_DE_FALLA", var_Falla, 1, 1
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "COD_VALIDACION", var_cod_val, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "MONTO", var_monto, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "COD_VERIFICADOR", var_cod_verif, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "REF_FORMULARIO", var_ref_form, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_MOTIVO_TICKET", var_mot_ticket, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_ASISTENTE_SIC", var_asist, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_SUPERVISOR_SIC", var_super, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_MOTIVO_CONSULTA_PFS", var_consulta, 1, 2
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "US_CREACION", UCase(var_usuario), 1, 1
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "TS_CREACION", Date, 1, 12
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "US_ULT_MODIF", UCase(var_usuario), 1, 1
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "TS_ULT_MODIF", Date, 1, 12
    oradatabase.Parameters.Add "COD_TIPO_VALIDACION", a1, 1, 96
    oradatabase.ExecuteSQL cad

End Sub
```

Comment: Estimado, al parecer se ve bien la sintaxis, podrías revisar una segunda vez en la base de datos si existen todas las columnas que nombras, puede que el problema vaya por ese lado. Nunca está de mas.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada te recomiendo estudiar un poco sobre PL-SQL y sobre prácticas para evitar inyección SQL, te doy un ejemplo de como puedes implementar un insert:

## Codigo:

```
cad = "INSERT INTO CDJ.CDJ_CONSULTAS_PFS " +
" (ID_CONSULTA_PFS,FC_CONSULTA_PFS,ID_VLT) " +
" VALUES " +
" (:ID_CONSULTA_PFS, :FC_CONSULTA_PFS, :ID_VLT);"

oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_CONSULTA_PFS", reg_actual, 1, 1
oradatabase.Parameters.Add "FC_CONSULTA_PFS", Date, 1, 12
oradatabase.Parameters.Add "ID_VLT", var_slot, 1, 2
oradatabase.ExecuteSQL cad
```

## Explicación

En el string de la sentencia SQL debes declarar los parametros con el prefijo dos puntos ":" y posteriormente asignar los parametros por medio de la colección *Parameters* usando el método Add donde deberás poner en orden los parametros del método (Parametro, Valor, I/O, Tipo) Donde Parametro es el nombre que declaraste, Valor es el que tomarás de tu formulario o variable, I/O es si el parametro es entrada o salida, y finalmente el tipo donde 1 es VARCHAR, 2 es Number y 12 es Date.

## Referencias:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17727/sermthod002.htm#OOFOL426
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17727/serprop115.htm#OOFOL779

Comment: hmm .. me quedó claro . Al parecer es la sintaxis correcta para hacer un insert into desde alguna interfase que se conecta a Orecle. Yo tengo una aplicación en VB6 y parece que no toma algo de esta sintaxis, la he realizado tal cual, pero me sale un error 440 de caracter inválido ...

Comment: Finalmente el error ahora es  "invalid column name" , alguna idea ?